# T-SQL. Text of procedure call

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logging, stored-procedures

I'm trying to implement a generic logging for my stored procedures. The best solution I found is to use DBCC INPUTBUFFER, it returns the text of procedure call like:

```
DECLARE @a INT
SET @a = 1000
EXEC usp_Test @param = @a
```

But it has one limitation, the max length of this buffer is 4000. I have a lot of procedures that have table valued parameters and often they contain > 10000 records, so I can't log this call with this approach.

Is there any way to implement such logging without manual creating of 'Text of procedure call' in each procedure?

Comment: Have you considered using the built in SQL Server Auditing capabilities: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `DBCC INPUTBUFFER @SPID`, you can try to use the [dm_exec_sql_text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929.aspx)

It has a `nvarchar(max)` field as `Text` of the last SP.

Try to build a function for this code (expect the `@SPID` as int parameter):

```
--Select the sql_handle first for the given session ID
DECLARE @sqltext VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @sqltext = sql_handle
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = @SPID

--Select the last statement
SELECT TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sqltext)
```

An other way to use:

```
EXEC yourProcedure withYourParams
SELECT @sqltext = sql_handle FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = @@SPID

SELECT TEXT FROM ::fn_get_sql(@sqltext)
```

Instead of `@SPID` parameter for this, you can use the  `@@SPID`, but then this code segment will be integrated with your last SP call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately if it is a part of stored procedure it returns the code of stored procedure, not the code of its call. :(

Comment: True, but if you try to use the code only, with @@SPID, it should return the call. Can you try it?

Comment: I updated again with a simplified version of my first code. I tested it with one of my PRC and it returned the exact code what I wrote in query window on my SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Try to create a simple stored procedure and write this code as a part of it, and then run "EXEC SP"

Comment: Yes, I tried it, and read a bit on MSDN, it returns the whole batch.

Answer (score 0):

what about change data capture?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510744(v=sql.105).aspx

or an OUTPUT statement

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: And how is it going to help me?